# How to sum arrays in multidimentional array and add total array back in array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have the below array

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [group_description] => Group 1
                [services] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [service_id] => 1
                                [service_name] => Security
                                [service_total] => 10
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [service_id] => 4
                                [service_name] => Catering
                                [service_total] => 20
                            )
                    )
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [group_description] => Group 2
                [services] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [service_id] => 1
                                [service_name] => Security
                                [service_total] => 6
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [service_id] => 4
                                [service_name] => Catering
                                [service_total] => 15
                            )
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [service_id] => 5
                                [service_name] => Lighting
                                [service_total] => 8
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

I want to sum arrays that have the same service and create a total array and put in back in to array like so

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [group_description] => Group 1
                [services] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [service_id] => 1
                                [service_name] => Security
                                [service_total] => 10
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [service_id] => 4
                                [service_name] => Catering
                                [service_total] => 20
                            )
                    )
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [group_description] => Group 2
                [services] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [service_id] => 1
                                [service_name] => Security
                                [service_total] => 6
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [service_id] => 4
                                [service_name] => Catering
                                [service_total] => 15
                            )
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [service_id] => 5
                                [service_name] => Lighting
                                [service_total] => 8
                            )
                    )
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [group_description] => Total
                [services] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [service_id] => 1
                                [service_name] => Security
                                [service_total] => 16
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [service_id] => 4
                                [service_name] => Catering
                                [service_total] => 35
                            )
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [service_id] => 5
                                [service_name] => Lighting
                                [service_total] => 8
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

I have tried looping the array and creating a new array while loooping. I used a foreach loop then used the array_search function to see which I am busy with and append to new array. but it does not achieve what i want,I always end up with the same array. Like I am literally caught in a loop. I have seen many examples but i think my case is not similar to examples

```
     foreach ($array as $value) { 

       if(array_search($value['service_id], array_column($array, 'service_id')) !== false) {
                    $newArray['service_id'] = $value['service_id'];
                    $newArray['service_name'] = $value['service_name'];
                    $newArray['service_total'] = $value['service_total'] + $newArray['service_total'];

                } else{ 
                    $newArray[] = $value; 
                }  
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more than 1 foreach. Every deepest iteration you check if service is added. If yes, you add the current value, if not you add whole service. At the end you join to the current array.

```
function count_services($array)
{
    $service_list = [];
    foreach ($array as $row) {
        foreach ($row['services'] as $service) {
            if (isset($service_list[$service['service_id']])) {
                $service_list[$service['service_id']]['service_total'] += $service['service_total'];
            } else {
                $service_list[$service['service_id']] = $service;
            }
        }
    }

    return [
        'group_description' => 'Total',
        'services' => array_values($service_list)];
}

print_r(count_services($array));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [group_description] => Total
    [services] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [service_id] => 1
                    [service_name] => Security
                    [service_total] => 16
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [service_id] => 4
                    [service_name] => Catering
                    [service_total] => 35
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [service_id] => 5
                    [service_name] => Lighting
                    [service_total] => 8
                )

        )

)
```